# Loading Large Excel Files

Tags: .net, excel, file-upload

I'm using the OLEDB connection string for this and it appears that whenever I try to load an Excel file (I'm using .NET) it takes an incredibly loooong time.  This causes a timeout and most files greater than a certain size can't be loaded into the program. Is there any other way or pattern I can use to make everything work faster (The data loading I mean)?

I don't have the exact code but I just used a simple connection and a dataTable.Fill()

Comment: Can you at least post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settled for a slightly faster approach using DataReader. Looks like there's not a lot I could do to improve the speed.

Answer (score 0):

you could try doing the insert like

```
insert into mytable(col1,col2,col3)
select 1,2,3
union all
select 4,5,6
```

on the chance you're using sql server 2008 or better you could also do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstCol, SecondCol)
VALUES ('First',1),
('Second',2),
('Third',3),
('Fourth',4),
('Fifth',5)
```

this generally is much more efficient, though i'm not sure if you mean that the drag is on reading the file or inserting individual records.

Comment: Oh. sorry. I was looking more into reading the files faster than inserting.